# Need help in fixing javascript in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, widgets, embed

I am having a weird and frustrating problem regarding adding javascript to the posts in WordPress. Googled but no luck.

I am adding [widget](https://www.n2yo.com/widgets/) from the N2yo Satellite Tracking website to my website. In WordPress, to insert javascript, we simply paste the code in the text editor. I did the same and javascript was working but now the element is not working.

[Link to the page](https://smuneebali.com/satellite-tracking/international-space-station/)

Here is what I have tried to fix:

**I checked the page code using Inspect Element and it shows that JS is loading on the page:**
The problem here is that JS is being retrieved as `<p></p>` instead of the script.

**I did the same thing and made the post on [another domain](https://digitlyservices.com/?p=776&preview=1&_ppp=5838e2e894) using Wordpress too, and it worked.**

I deactivated all the plugins except Elementor and Elementor pro to find the conflicting plugin but it still didn't work.

Thanks in Advance.

JS used:

```
<script>
    var norad_n2yo = '43600';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.n2yo.com/js/widget-tracker.js"></script>
```

Comment: FWIW my antivirus flags up your page as having JS/Agent.OZD malicious code.

Comment: "In WordPress, to insert javascript, we simply paste the code in the text editor." That's not the WordPress way to do it—instead you should be [enqueueing](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) the JS file.

Comment: @PatJ if we use the Gutenberg HTML code element in WordPress and paste the above mentioned JS code, it displays the desired thing without enqueueing or doing anything. In fact, the other link I have added in the question has done the same thing. One is working but the other isn't. That's confusing.

Comment: The linked page is producing a pile of JavaScript parse errors. Fatal errors like these can completely kill script execution, depending on the case. But check your console - `widget-tracker.js` is throwing an error - some variable which is supposed to contain a reference to an HTML element is empty instead. It's not clear that this question is actually particular to WordPress or it's APIs - though I would agree with Pat in that it would be ideal to load the script by a more conventional means. Aside: the second "digitlyservices" link "has expired".